# How do you print a string in MATLAB in color?

Tags: matlab

Usually when you print a string in MATLAB:

```
disp('this will print black letters')
```

Can it be printed in color instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you `fprintf()` to `stderr`, it can come out in another colour (depending on your preferences, I think).

There is [undocumented functionality](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cprintf-display-formatted-color-text-in-command-window/) you can (ab)use to get more than this, though.

Comment: Shortcut: the "undocumented functionality" page describes a function called [`cprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24093), as mentioned by @RWALLS, and is available on the MATLAB File Exchange via [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24093).

Answer (score 4):

In MATLAB Central-File, I find this function:  [`cprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24093)

I hope this solve your question.