# Coloured outputs

Tags: matlab

how is it possible to write an output in color? I'd like to distinguish my lines better.

Also, is it possible to make it systematic. For example: k = 100, and I'd like to have 1, 11, 21, 31 red; 2, 12, 22, 32 blue; 3, 13, 33, 43 green; etc.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to be clearer... what is an "answer"?

Comment: I believe that you are asking for coloring the output lines inside MATLAB editor, and you search for a custom systematic method to color the lines differently resulting in better readability. I am not aware if such an answer exists. A complex workaround is making a GUI with Guide, print your results in a text box and color them differently. But I don't consider this a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you print a string in MATLAB in color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457461/how-do-you-print-a-string-in-matlab-in-color)

Answer (score 2):

Automatically changing colors in the command window is not officially possible.

However, using Yair Altman's [CPRINTF](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cprintf-display-formatted-color-text-in-command-window/), you can print differently colored text to the command window. Thus, if you were producing output from a loop, you could cycle through a list of colors and use `cprintf` instead of `disp` or `fprintf` to display text.

Note that it might be possible to invoke `cprintf` as a callback that is executed whenever you hit the return key as you enter text (and you can store the last used color in the `UserData` of the command window), but this is very deep in undocumented territory.