# Draw two lines above a matrix in the command window

Tags: matlab, matrix

so I have an N-by-N matrix and I want to draw two lines above the matrix when this will be shown in the workspace. Exactly I want to draw a red line on the i-th row and a red line on the j-th column. There is a way to do it? Thank you!

My matrix is:

```
n_real=5;
M=magic(n_real);
```

Comment: How are you currently drawing the matrix? Can you give an example, e.g. with the matrix (`magic(4)`)

Comment: If you're wanting to change the color of text that is displayed in the Command Window, I'd take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1457461/52738).

Comment: Change the color can be an idea but i prefer to draw the lines. The post has been edit.

Comment: @iacopo: What do you mean "draw lines"? You could use ASCII characters like `|` and `-`, but you can't draw lines in the Command Window like you can in a figure.

Comment: This is my question, there is a way to draw some lines in the command window?

Comment: *"command window"* and *"workspace"* are entirely different things

Comment: Yes sorry, there is a way or not?

Comment: by drawing lines do you mean striking through the letters?

Comment: Yes i mean a line which goes from the element (i,1) to the element (i,n_real) for example

Comment: Something like this: `char(uint16([95 818 49   818    95   818    95   818    95   818    95   818    50   818    95   818    95   818    95 818    95   818    95   818    51   818]))` would print `'_̲1̲_̲_̲_̲_̲2̲_̲_̲_̲_̲_̲3̲'`. I can't think of any way to draw a (connected) vertical line. I would prefer what gnovice suggested if I have to do it

Comment: Or., something like change the color of a column and a row of the matrix which will be seen in the command window? How to do it?

Comment: gnovice has already provided you the link!

Comment: yes but i don't understand how to apply these functions to a matrix